# XQuery - Variables in function definition

Tags: xquery

Is it possible to declare a variable to be used only inside of function declaration? If so - how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XQuery Scripting to declare local variables.

```
declare %a:sequential function local:func() {
  variable $var := ....;
  ...actual code...
}
```

XQuery Scripting is described in the following tutorial: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/doc/latest/zorba/html/scripting_tutorial.html

Comment: It is based from this specification: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/doc/latest/zorba/html/scripting_spec.html

Answer (score 9):

Variable declaration can only be placed in the prolog of a query, but you can wrap your function code with a FLWOR expression, consisting of a single LET and RETURN clause. An example:

```
declare function local:func() {
   let $var := ...your variable...
   return
      ...your actual code...
};
```

Hope this helps,
Christian

Comment: Can I add only one variable this way?